# In Xcode 4 GM, how do I turn on LLDB? All I see is GDB

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, xcode4, lldb

In the scheme run debugger popup, all it shows is 'None' and 'GDB'. This is for an iPad 4.2 simulator built with LLVM.

Comment: Isn't the current GM labeled "beta" and thus still covered by NDA?

Comment: Hmm good question, its not clear.

Comment: Yes, Xcode 4 is still under NDA and in theory you risk losing your Apple Developer status if you discuss it publicly.

Comment: Looks like still not live. Oh well.

Comment: You can, however, discuss it at http://devforums.apple.com/

Comment: Well, now as Xcode 4 is released, does anyone actually know the answer?

Answer (score 18):

You can't. In words of an Apple employee, [LLDB is not available for iOS development yet](https://devforums.apple.com/message/378379#378379). As of july 2011 it is unknown when LLDB will become available for iOS.

In Xcode 4.0.2 your only option is GDB.  In Xcode 4.2 you have LLDB as an option, but you can't use it:
[image]

The [LLDB project](http://lldb.llvm.org/) doesn't list a date for iOS support. The [FAQ](http://lldb.llvm.org/faq.html) says:

> Q: What targets does LLDB currently support?
>   Mac OS X native debugging
>   for i386 and x86_64 targets.

And the WWDC 2011 sessions that talk about LLDB (eg: 321 Migrating to LLDB) don't mention anything about iOS devices.

Comment: This is fairly obvious if you create a Mac OS X project and an iOS project. The former has LLDB available in the scheme editor; the latter doesn't. Clearly, this is a conscious decision and we iOS developers will just have to wait a while.

Comment: It looks like it's available in 4.1. I've no idea if it's a good choice yet.

Answer (score 4):

LLDB is shipping with XCode 4.0.1 that you can buy from Apple's AppStore.

You only have to switch to LLDB. You can do that by pressing Option key when clicking on "Run" and choose LLDB instead of CDB (third drop down box on Info tab).

Here's XCode (can be found in "About XCode) that I have:

```
Version:    4.0 (4A1006)
  Location: /Developer
  Applications:
  Xcode:    4.0.1 (99)
  Instruments:  4.0 (3538)
  Dashcode: 3.0.2 (333)
  SDKs:
  Mac OS X:
  10.6: (4A1006)
  iPhone OS:
  3.2:  (7B500)
  4.3:  (8F191m)
  iPhone Simulator:
  3.2:  (7W367a)
  4.0:  (8A400)
  4.1:  (8B117)
  4.2:  (8C134)
  4.3:  (8F192)
```

Answer (score 4):

LLDB debugging is enabled in iOS with the release of Xcode 4.3.